# What evolutionary abilities would crepuscular elves have?

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, fantasy-races

In my universe elves are mainly [crepuscular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crepuscular), active mostly at twilight and dawn while prey is most vulnerable. They hunt mostly large prey like deer, boar, etc.. They have sharp claws and teeth which help them fight in short range when arrows don't immediately kill.

Would they gain increased night vision and if so how?

Comment: Twilight and dawn cover less than 2 hours per day. Considering that hunting is never 100% effective, I don't think they are going to last long.

Comment: What are their preys? This is important as elves may have trained themselves to exploit the prey weakness and develop trait suitable for it.

Comment: To build on @L.Dutch they have limited access to prey. How animals handle that IRL is they sleep. A lot. Wolves sleep nearly half the day. Same with big cats (male lions up to 20h). This provides a balance in energy expended vs resources gathered. Also, if your elves aren't solely carnivorous they will be able to harvest various berries/fruits/grains.

Comment: One other bit, 'evolve' to handle this? That's a stretch of the definition. Learn, adapt, manipulate, overcome might be better. Evolve implies multiple generations to implement. How long do they live? If it's quasi traditional then 1Ky. So any evolving might well miss local abundant prey as they can be hunted to extinction in a single elf generation. If not by the elves themselves then those they are competition with.

Comment: Evolutionary question are nearly impossible to answer since, by definition, given enough time they'd evolve almost anything.  Frankly, what they'd evolve is a change in eyesight to permit balanced dirunal activity as a precedent to intelligence.

Comment: Jordan, I can't vote to reopen as the question is your question is no less broad after the edits.  The issue is "... and if so, how?"  What does that mean?  What are you trying to achieve in your story with the answer to this question?  If your story is better with increased night vision, why not simply write it that way?  What does knowing about "how" (whatever that means) do to help you?

Answer (score 1):

*Traits common to the hinterlands*

Since they are mystical creatures that inhabit a border between places or times, they will develop traits befitting such places...

They may be able to become invisible if looked directly upon rather than from peripheral vision.

They may be able to travel unexpected distances between blinks.

They may develop the ability to appear as though bobbing lanterns off at some variable and changing distance and direction.

They may emits sounds similar to children laughing or whispering winds that seem to be calling out names.

They may be able to mimic forest and prairie animals crossing paths directly in front of someone they wish to observe more closely.

They may become able to appear as a helping stranger to aid a weary, good hearted traveler.

Comment: I like the various attributes you suggest. Not sure if they would hunt or help a traveler. Either are possible, I suppose.

Comment: @dcy665 yes either depending on the story in play or how capricious this group of elves is. I made this answer community... all are folklore examples I've heard or read over time of hinterland characteristics... not necessarily just elves, but certainly of some borderland inhabitants. I thought others may recognize some of these and know similar examples to share.

Comment: I recall a story with creatures that were visible only in peripheral vision. Nobody could focus on them, but looking aside quickly might catch one momentarily.